# Custom admin menu icon in WordPress ? Custom Svg

Tags: wordpress

How can I change the default WordPress dashboard menu icons?
But for the new menu, I don't want for the ones that are in the menu by default.
note: I do not want for a new post. For the default menu icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change menu icon like this : Also you replace it with image too.

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');
function my_init() {
    register_post_type('labs', [
        'label' => 'Labs',
        // .. ect
        'menu_icon' => 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' . base64_encode('<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="black" d="M1591 1448q56 89 21.5 152.5t-140.5 63.5h-1152q-106 0-140.5-63.5t21.5-152.5l503-793v-399h-64q-26 0-45-19t-19-45 19-45 45-19h512q26 0 45 19t19 45-19 45-45 19h-64v399zm-779-725l-272 429h712l-272-429-20-31v-436h-128v436z"/></svg>')
     ]);
}
```

Also you can use custom css for admin menu:

```
#adminmenu #toplevel_page_yourpageid .menu-icon-generic div.wp-menu-image:before {
font-family: your_font !important;
content: '\eiconid';
font-size: 1.3em!important;}
```

Comment: thank you . I do not want for a new post. For the default menu icons

Comment: You can use custom css for it.

Comment: you `admin_head` for custom css